# How to centre <img> which has a z index?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am having trouble centering an image, at the moment, it stays to the left. The  concept is that when I click the image, the larger version of the image pops us.

HTML:

```
<div class="photoposition" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showImage('imagesinsurgent/in21.jpg');">
    <img src="imagesinsurgent/in21.jpg" class="scaledownlandscape"/>
    <p class="photogalleryp"></p>
</div>
<div id="largeImgPanel" onclick="hideMe(this);">
    <img id="largeImg" style="height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photoposition{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 53px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.scaledownlandscape{
    width: 250px;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.divspan{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#largeImgPanel {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
    margin-top: 141px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function showImage(imgName) {
    document.getElementById('largeImg').src = imgName;
    showLargeImagePanel();
    unselectAll();
}

function showLargeImagePanel() {    
    document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function unselectAll() {
    if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
    if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
}

function hideMe(obj) {
    obj.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: try adding `right:0` to `#largeImgPanel`.

Comment: `right: 0` didn't work

Comment: could you please show your code in a fiddle..

Comment: How do you add a fiddle? @Lal

Comment: copy your html,css and javascript in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I found the solution already, but thanks for helping :) @Lal

Comment: Oh great.. :) Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `#largeImgPanel` 100% width and center align the content

```
#largeImgPanel {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
    margin-top: 141px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/neqeqibiyo/edit?html,css,output)